# Xcode tries to push git submodule

Tags: xcode, git

I've added a a git submodule to my project, but whenever I try to push to git using Xcode it wants to push the submodule project as well.

[image]

Since I have read-only access to the artemis repo, I can't push. I can get around this by downloading a zip of the artemis project and including that, but then I lose the `git submodule update` functionality.